# HTTP 403.9 - Access Forbidden: Too many users are connected

Tags: iis

I have created an application in VStudio. It ran nicely in debugging mode, but my computer became slower and slower as I worked until it finaly became frozen.
after I manualy restarted it, the app wasn't running any more in debug and I get this execption in the browser.

1. Only I am connected right now to the app.
2. I have restarted the computer so there coudn't be any instance of a client connected
3. I have removed and reinstalled the IIS

what is wrong?

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the event log? What kind of application is it? How / what requests are you sending to IIS?

Answer (score 6):

Is this happening on an XP Pro development machine? Sometimes, if you have many javascripts/images/css files on a page as well as IFrames and multiple AJAX calls, your one page will run out of connections in a development environment. There are two ways to overcome this.

1. **Switch off HTTP Keep-Alives.** In IIS manager, go to the Web Site tab and under connections, uncheck the HTTP Keep-Alives Enabled checkbox. **Don't do this in a production environment** as it will slow down your site a lot.
2. **Increase the number of concurrent connections.**
   You’re limited by default to 10 concurrent connections by design, but this can be increased. First, make sure your default windows script host is set to the console (cscript.exe) one. In a command prompt run:

   cscript //h:cscript

Next, let’s increase the connection limit to 40.

```
C:\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil set w3svc/MaxConnections 40
```

You can make the IIS connection timeout more aggressive so connections don’t last as long.

Set the default script host back to windows:

```
cscript //h:wscript
```

Comment: You could have credited the source: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/06/uncrippling-windows-xps-iis-51.html

Comment: True, I could have. Thanks, but that was not the source. You can find the same post on many blogs and forums, so it would be impossible to be sure which is the original without trawling the entire internet and looking at the date of each posting.

Answer (score 0):

Only 2 concurrent connections are allowed for localhost account. Since you are testing the website on your server and I suppose you are using IE as your browser.

When IE requests for the web page 2 connections are maintained. This is the possible reason for the error you are seeing.